# Finding the radius of convergence for the given series.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

How to find out the radius of convergence for $\sum x^{n!}$? I tried the ratio and the root test. But no luck. Kindly help !

Comment: Hint: The radius of convergence $R$ of the series $\sum\limits_na_nx^n$ is *characterized* by the fact that $a_nr^n\to0$ for every $r<R$ and that $(a_nr^n)$ is unbounded for every $r>R$. Thus?

Comment: Well it obviously diverges for $|x| \geq 1$ and converges for $|x|<1$ (e.g. by comparison with $\sum x^n$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the radius of convergence of the series

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}c_nx^{n},
\end{equation*}

use the definition

\begin{equation*}
l:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^{1/n}.
\end{equation*}

Therefore we have

\begin{equation*}
l=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1)^{1/{n!}}=1\Rightarrow R=1.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 2):

According to Cauchy-Hadamard, the radius of convergence $r$ of $\sum a_nx^n$ is given by 
$$\tag1\frac 1r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$$
For your example, $a_n=1$ if $n=k!$ for some $k>1$, $a_1=2$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise. As with any 0-1-sequence that is $1$ infinitely often, the limes superior in $(1)$ equals $1$, henec also $r=1$.